# Automorphism Graph

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

I have this given graph: $G=(\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}, \{(1,3),(3,6),(6,1),(2,5),(5,4),(5,7)\})$

Is the automorphism for this graph only the id?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: what do u mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph looks like this:

[image]

Can you see some automorphisms of the triangle?  Of the three-pointed star?  Can you get automorphisms of the whole graph from those?

Comment: sry i edited my question 8 is not in the set of vertices

Comment: OK, so erase the 8.

Comment: (1)(36),(24)(57)?

Comment: 5 is the only vertex of degree 3.  Any automorphism must keep it fixed.

Comment: the right answer is {id, (47), (136),(163), (47)(136), (47)(163)}

Comment: Is that supposed to be a **directed** graph?  Because if it's undirected,  those are not all the automorphisms.

Comment: it is a directed graph sry didn't mention that fact